# Rails construction not works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why do this string

```
@order.errors.empty? ? redirect_to @order : render "new"
```

in my code not working? The error is:

```
/home/user/sites/water/app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' @order.errors.empty? ? redirect_to @order : render "new" ^
```

Comment: Is that line part of any loop? Please post the controller action where you are using it.

Comment: `@order = Order.create(order_params)
@order.errors.empty? ? redirect_to @order : render "new"`. I want to use this construction instead if..else

Comment: what if you use simple if and else, does it make difference.?

Comment: I'm guiding this documentation https://github.com/styleguide/ruby. It says, when expression is simple, use ? and : instead if .... else

Comment: added the answer for your case. i think that will help. if you want to send notice and flash messages on redirection. please use simple if and else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if you want your redirect and render in one line

```
@order.errors.empty? ? (redirect_to @order) : (render "new")
```